# sort list of files in R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to sort a list of files. the order I get by using str_sort is the same as the default:

```
list.files('sim')
     [1] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.037.csv"    "Intercept_simulation_0_0.074.csv"   
     [3] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.099.csv"    "Intercept_simulation_0_0.csv"       
     [5] "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.074.csv"
     [7] "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.csv"    
     [9] "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.074.csv"
    [11] "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.csv"    
    [13] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.074.csv"
    [15] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.csv"    
    [17] "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.074.csv"
    [19] "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.csv"
```

I would like to order in a way such *_0_0.csv will be before *_0_0.037.csv; *_0.02_0.csv before *_0.02_0.037; etc
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the relevant part from the string and then use `order`

```
x[order(sub(".*?(\\d.*)\\.csv", "\\1", x))]

# [1] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.csv"        "Intercept_simulation_0_0.037.csv"   
# [3] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.074.csv"    "Intercept_simulation_0_0.099.csv"   
# [5] "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.037.csv"
# [7] "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.099.csv"
# [9] "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.037.csv"
#[11] "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.099.csv"
#[13] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.037.csv"
#[15] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.099.csv"
#[17] "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.037.csv"
#[19] "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.099.csv"
```

where output from `sub` is

```
sub(".*?(\\d.*)\\.csv", "\\1", x)
# [1] "0_0.037"    "0_0.074"    "0_0.099"    "0_0"    "0.02_0.037" "0.02_0.074"    
#     "0.02_0.099" "0.02_0"  "0.04_0.037" "0.04_0.074" "0.04_0.099" "0.04_0"        
#     "0.06_0.037" "0.06_0.074" "0.06_0.099" "0.06_0"  "0.08_0.037" "0.08_0.074" 
#     "0.08_0.099" "0.08_0"
```

---

Well, in this case `mixedsort` from `gtools` works straight out of the box

```
gtools::mixedsort(x)
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Intercept_simulation_0_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` with `order`

```
x[order(gsub(".*[a-z]_|\\.csv", "", x))]
#[1] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.csv"        "Intercept_simulation_0_0.037.csv"    "Intercept_simulation_0_0.074.csv"   
#[4] "Intercept_simulation_0_0.099.csv"    "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.037.csv"
#[7] "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.csv"    
#[10] "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.099.csv"
#[13] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.037.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.074.csv"
#[16] "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.099.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.csv"     "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.037.csv"
#[19] "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.074.csv" "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.099.csv"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("Intercept_simulation_0_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.02_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.04_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.06_0.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.037.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.074.csv", 
"Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.099.csv", "Intercept_simulation_0.08_0.csv")
```